# merging sublists based on repeated values in another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have 2 lists from which I would like to create a dict.

my list1 is:

```
[1,2,2,3]
```

my list2 is:

```
[['A','B'],['J','K'],[L'','M'],['W','X']]
```

I would like to make a

```
dict(zip(list1,list2))
```

However given that list1 has a repeated key I am loosing one key 2 with its values.

So I  would like to join the sublists of list2 based on the repeated values in list 1 .

list1 and list2 are indexed in same order.

The desired output would be :

```
[['A','B'],['J','K','L','M'],['W','X']]
```

So I can remove dups of list1 and make the

```
dict(zip(list1_without_dups,list2_merged_sublists))
```

Sorry I do not include my try but i have been seeking for similar issues unsuccesfully and not sure how to face it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst1 = [1,2,2,3]
lst2 = [['A','B'],['J','K'],['L','M'],['W','X']]

d = defaultdict(list)

for x, y in zip(lst1, lst2):
    d[x].extend(y)

print(d)
```

which outputs:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['A', 'B'], 2: ['J', 'K', 'L', 'M'], 3: ['W', 'X']})
```

You can now extract values to get the desired list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby as g, chain as c
d =  [1,2,2,3]
new_d = [['A','B'],['J','K'],['L','M'],['W','X']]
r = [list(c(*[j for _, j in b])) for _, b in g(list(zip(d, new_d)), key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B'], ['J', 'K', 'L', 'M'], ['W', 'X']]
```